# Is it possible to configure the way latexmk know there is not known cross-reference

Tags: latexmk, reledmac

When there is a reference not defined in a `.tex` file, latexmk can find it and send a final message like

> Reference `B-U:identification' on page 22 undefined on input line 547

It seems latexmk look on the message in the `.log` file which look like

> LaTeX Warning: Reference `B-U:identification' on page 22 undefined on input line 547.

However the false crossref produce by a use `\edlabel` and `\edlineref` commands of reledmac produce warning message like the following

> Package reledmac Warning: Reference `BHG1852:doxologie-fils:start' on page 22 undefined ...

And latexmk does not recognize them.

Is is possible to configure latexmk to recognize these? I didn't see anything on the handbook.